# Can Google in-app billing/ Paypal sdk support delayed payment?

Tags: android, paypal, oauth-2.0, in-app-purchase

I am trying to develop an application that allows user A and user B make delayed transaction. That means if A wants to buy service from B, he has to pay a certain amount first. If B indeed provides the service to A, he would then get what he earns and I would get some commission from this. Otherwise, money would be returned back to A. As I research on mobile payment, it seems that oAuth allows "delayed" payment.

So I wonder if that means Google in-app billing and Paypal sdk could satisfy my need of having "delayed" payment. Also, how could I get the commission from the transaction? Let's say I want to have 10% commission. Should I get 100% of the amount first and give 90% to B? Is there a better way of doing so? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Before you offer such a service, I advise you to check regulations & legal responsibilities in your area (country and state level) around escrow services. It's a bit of a legal minefield... smells like an escrow service, which could get you in hot wter. Just friendly advice, do with it what you will :).

Comment: Thank you. Actually we've been doing some research on legal aspect and hope we could solve this issue :)

Comment: Then good luck, and I hope you build a great product! I think escrow can be quite useful. To get retention of custom scheduling and commission fees and such you are probably going to need to build the relationship between the initial and delayed payment yourself.

Comment: Then it seems I have to change the payment method. Thanks.